Film featuring advert for 'Stay Put' lipstick
Whilst rewatching Mad Men memories of an old film came to mind and I'd like help identifying it.
American film, made/set in late 50's early 60's.
Starred beautiful woman/bombshell (a Marilyn Monroe type - but not her)
Set in the world of advertising
Featured a commercial (as part of the story/plot) for Stay Put lipstick.
Might have featured Groucho Marx in a small role (this fact could be wrong)
Its at least 15 years since I saw it and so I can't really remember too many specifics, but hoping the above is enough - the more I think of the lead actress the more famous/iconic I think she was.

Sounds like Will Success Spoil Rock Hunter?  from 1957. It stars Jayne Mansfield, has a cameo by Groucho Marx and is about a copywriter whose agency advertises Stay Put lipstick. Here's the trailer:



